# Connecting a Texas Instruments TI-84 Plus CE to an Ubuntu computer

Tags: texas-instruments

I have recently acquired a Texas Instruments TI-84 Plus CE graphing calculator. I have some interest in connecting it to a computer to download, write, and upload programs to the calculator, and also to manage its memory. I know that this is possible on Windows with the TI Connect CE software, but I use an Ubuntu machine primarily. I'm wondering if there's any method or software out there that will allow me to hook up the calculator and view and edit its memory, particularly programs - basically a Linux equivalent of the TI Connect software. I have tried TILP, but it only supports the TI-84 Plus and not the TI-84 Plus CE.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

System Version:
Ubuntu 14.04 LTE

(P.S. If there are any problems with my question or how it's phrased please tell me in a comment and I'll attempt to correct it.)

Comment: Try http://lpg.ticalc.org/prj_tilp/features.html

Comment: @Jrican I forgot to mention, i have tried TILP and it doesn't work with my calculator model

Answer (score 2):

I think that TILP II v2.18 has support for a TI-84 Plus CE where as TILP II v2.17 doesn't. So my advice is to check your version of TILP and get v2.18.
You can download it here: http://www.ticalc.org/archives/files/fileinfo/374/37480.html

Hope this helps :-)